# How to remove special characters in column with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.0

I participate in a project and met a bad design by others,we have a table called task and each task has many users,the task table is as below:

```
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id             | varchar(40)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name           | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| task_users     | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

and the user is stored like `aaa,bbb,ccc` in `task_users` column,which means many user id are put into one column,I know this a very bad design but since it's an old project,I can not modify the table design.

Now I have a problem,if the user is deleted,how can I remove it from the `task_users` column?

the user id is generated by UUID and it's at fixed length with 32 characters,so each user id is unique,such as `40cf5f01eb2f4d2c954412f27b3bf6eb`,but the problem is that the user id may appaer in any position of the `task_users` column,so I do not know how to remove it

```
aaa,40cf5f01eb2f4d2c954412f27b3bf6eb,bbb -- in center
40cf5f01eb2f4d2c954412f27b3bf6eb,aaa,bbb -- in head
aaa,bbb,40cf5f01eb2f4d2c954412f27b3bf6eb -- in end
```

when remove the user id,the updated result is like

```
   aaa,bbb
```

I want to know can we use one update sql to remove the specified user id and still keep the same data format?

Note:I am doing it in a MySQL stored procedure,additional variable may be helpful,but I still want to just use one sql to do it,the MySQL version is **5.0**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function to replace specified user identificator with empty string.

Comment: @Alexander Can you add an example? I have considered using regex,but the key point is how to keep the same format,it's not just simple replace it with empty,since this will add duplicate `,`

Comment: I'm sorry, the function is able since MySQL 8.0

Comment: @Alexander it's doesn't matter,I am very painful with this bad table design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we can do this with a single query:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET task_users = SUBSTRING(
    REPLACE(CONCAT(',', task_users, ','), CONCAT(',', uid, ','), ','),
    2,
    LENGTH(task_users) - LENGTH(uid) - 1)
WHERE task_users REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', uid, '[[:>:]]');
```

[image]

Here is a link to a demo (to be used *only* for testing purposes):

### Demo

This answer uses a trick, by which we append commas to the start and end of the `task_users` string.  Then, we compare a given user ID by also appending commas to its start and end.  If a match is found, we replace with just a single comma.  But, this leaves the replacement still with its starting and ending commas, so we remove those with a substring operation.

SQL Olympics aside, hopefully you can see by the complexity of these answers that working with CSV data in a SQL database can be a real headache.  Maybe you can even use this page as evidence to your colleagues that the table design needs to change.

Comment: Oh, that's clever. Similar to what you see searching HTML class attributes with XPath, ie wrapping the entire string in the delimiter.

Comment: @Phil I couldn't get anything to work with your SQLFiddle demo (typical behavior), but I did get it working with Rextester.  Check the demo link if you are interested.

Comment: SQLFiddle is flakey most of the time but here's your answer as a demo there ~ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd4bb/1 (with UPDATE instead of SELECT)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's the answer that I want,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try this `CASE` expression where `uid` is the argument to your stored procedure...

```sql
UPDATE `task` SET `task_users` = CASE
  -- at the start
  WHEN `task_users` LIKE CONCAT(uid, ',%')
    THEN REPLACE(`task_users`, CONCAT(uid, ','), '')
  -- at the end
  WHEN `task_users` LIKE CONCAT('%,', uid)
    THEN REPLACE(`task_users`, CONCAT(',', uid), '')
  -- in the middle
  WHEN `task_users` LIKE CONCAT('%,', uid, ',%')
    THEN REPLACE(`task_users`, CONCAT(',', uid, ','), ',')
  -- only that user
  ELSE ''
END
WHERE `task_users` LIKE CONCAT('%', uid, '%');
```

Demo ~ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d2baa/1

---

Original *"four queries"* answer below

```sql
-- only that user
UPDATE `task`
SET `task_users` = ''
WHERE `task_users` = uid;

-- at start
UPDATE `task`
SET `task_users` = REPLACE(`task_users`, CONCAT(uid, ','), '')
WHERE `task_users` LIKE CONCAT(uid, ',%');

-- at end
UPDATE `task`
SET `task_users` = REPLACE(`task_users`, CONCAT(',', uid), '')
WHERE `task_users` LIKE CONCAT('%,', uid);

-- in the middle
UPDATE `task`
SET `task_users` = REPLACE(`task_users`, CONCAT(',', uid, ','), ',')
WHERE `task_users` LIKE CONCAT('%,', uid, ',%');
```

Demo ~ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e9b9bb/1

Comment: Thanks for your answer,your solution need four separate sql,in my question,I am wonder if we can use just one sql to do it

Comment: @lucumt, it is possible to use multiple sql queries within a [custom procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html).

Comment: @lucumt I've updated my answer with a potential _single-query"_ solution (untested yet)

Comment: Ok, tested it now. Works fine on MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 2):

You could use following expression to replace specified user identificator with empty string:

```
SET @userID = '40cf5f01eb2f4d2c954412f27b3bf6eb';

UPDATE `task`
SET task_users = REGEXP_REPLACE(task_users, CONCAT('(,', @userID, '|', @userID, ',?)'), '');
```

Or add `WHERE` clause to filter records for update:

```
UPDATE `task`
SET task_users = REGEXP_REPLACE(task_users, CONCAT('(,', @userID, '|', @userID, ',?)'), '');
WHERE task_users RLIKE CONCAT('(^|,)', @userID,'(,|$)')
```

**Note**, the [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function was added in the MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Sorry my database version is **5.0**

Comment: Your `LIKE` version has a potential problem, should a `@userName` happen to also be a substring of another username.  Use `REGEXP` with word boundaries instead.  But suggesting a regex replacement is a generally good idea here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP says they're all unique 32 character strings so the chance of a false positive is zero

Comment: @Phil Thanks for clarifying, though in general for someone else reading this question in the future, it might be a concern for him.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sure, that makes a lot of sense and I'm sure many of the other terrible _CSV_ implementations out there don't enjoy the luxury of unique, fixed length values. My answer suffers the same issue as this one

Comment: Thank you, @TimBiegeleisen. You are right! I have updated the answer.